# converting epoch into month

Tags: javascript, datetime, epoch

I wanted to convert the epoch '1326067200000' into month, i.e., 'January'.

```
var d = new Date(1326067200000).format("%B");
print (d);
```

Not working though.

What's the easiest and elegant way of doing it?

Comment: There is just [`toLocaleFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat) to do exactly what you want, but there is almost no support for it. The other option is just `getMonth()` and a switch ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```
 var month = new Date(1326067200000).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: 'short'})
```

At the time of writing, you'll have to patch Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility

Alternatively, you can get a 0-numbered month with `getMonth()`:

```
var monthNames = ['Jan','Feb','Mar']
var month = monthNames[new Date(1326067200000).getMonth()];
```